# CSS tabs with arrows and full background color hovers

Tags: html, css

I got the following tab bar navigation which I would like to do in CSS only:

[image: Tab Navigation bar]

On this screen, I have marked the last element "Endergebnis" as `.active` or `:hover`.

I thought about creating the arrows as pseudo elements with `position: absolute`, although about multiple elements using `transform: rotate(x deg)`, but in every solution I do not know how to give each tab a full filling background-color.

Can anybody give me a good hint?

Comment: Please post your code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a pseudo and transform :

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  border: solid;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: solid;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  ;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li+li {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 3em;
}

li {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

li:hover,
li:hover+li:before,
li.active,
li.active+li:before {
  background: lightblue;
}

li:hover:before,
li.active:before {
  background: white;
}

li:last-child:after,
li+li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.2em;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right: solid;
  border-top: solid;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 3px -3px 6px -3px gray;/* a shadow effect can be added too */
  width: 3em;
  transform: rotate(30deg) skewy(30deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

li:last-child:after {
  right: -1.5em;
  background: inherit;
}

li+li:before {
  left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <ul>
    <li> one </li>
    <li> two </li>
    <li> three </li>
    <li> four </li>
    <li class="active"> Active </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options to do this:

1. You create a triangle with CSS. In your example, you would need to have 2 triangles overlapping each other, because creating a triangle with CSS requires borders, and you cannot add a border to a border. You can use the following snippet:

```css
.box {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.box + .box {
  border-left: 0;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.box:after,
.box:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-left: 20px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box:before {
  border-top: 21px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left: 21px solid black;
  top: -1px;
  right: -21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Website</div><div class="box">About Me</div><div class="box">Contact</div>
```

2. You can create a regular quadratic element and rotate it 45deg with the following statement. You need to make sure to have the correct `z-index` set.

   ```
    transform: rotate(45deg);
   ```

I would go for the second option, as you are much more flexible.

---

## Edit by [sudipto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7791826/sudipto)

Here's how you can do it without using CSS transformation:
(I am using transparent borders with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes instead.)

```css
body {
  background: #eff4f7;
  padding: 30px;
}

.breadcrumb-wrap {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #64768a;
  border: 2px solid #d7dade;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.breadcrumb-title {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #d7dade;
}

.breadcrumb li {
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: #64768a;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 50px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.breadcrumb li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid #d7dade;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child a {
  background: #eff4f7;
  color: #64768a;
  cursor: default;
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child a:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child a:after {
  border-left-color: #eff4f7;
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  background: #eef3f6;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #eef3f6;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb-wrap">
  <div class="breadcrumb-title">Teams</div>
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Meldungen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Zulassung</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Endergebnis</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```